# ReactNative SwitchSelector

Tags: react-native

I`m using Switchselector on my app. I have have to disable item, is it posible ? For exaampledepending on some event I want do disable 02:00
[image]

```
let myOptions = [{label: 'Morning', value: 'morning'},{label: 'Afternoon', value: 'afternoon'},{label: 'Evening', value: 'evening'}]

<SwitchSelector
    selectedColor={'#ffffff'}
    buttonColor={'#9347C0'}
    options={myOptins}
    initial={2}
    onPress={daytime => this.setState({daytime})}
  />
```

For some cases I need only 2 options, for others 3 or 1.

Comment: Post some code and explain yourself a little further. Not much we can do with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes using `disabled:{true}`, by default it is false